# What are the Roman Catholic pilgrimages in Northern America?

Tags: catholicism, religious-practice

In France there are several "formal" and organised catholic pilgrimage each year to Lourdes, Chartres, Vezelay for boy-scouts and other shrines that occures a few times, sometimes even once a year and are an occasion of gathering around faith. What are, if they exist, the organised pilgrimages equivalent in America? Is there a database of them?

I googled a bit and only found the Marian Days for the Vietnamese American Roman Catholics.

By catholic I mean *the branch of the Christian Church that accepts the Pope as its leader and is based in the Vatican in Rome.*

Comment: Are you asking for recognized places that are sacred sites for pilgrims or for more formal pilgrimages in North America that are organized like that of the Chartres - Paris pilgrimage?

Comment: @KenGraham Thanks for considering, I am aking for formal and organized pilgrimages like Paris- Chartres' one either in North, South or Latin America if it isn't too broad.

Comment: I think there are several pilgrimage places in Latin America (Our Lady of Guadalupe for sure), I think you should limit this to the United States or ask another question

Comment: @PeterTurner Understood, I will limit to the United States **and** Canada if it ever exists some

Answer (score 1):

The Society of St. Pius X has been hosting annual U.S. pilgrimages for nearly two decades. From [their site](http://sspx.org/en/news-events/news/3-unique-pilgrimages-america-14460):

> **Pascua Florida Pilgrimage to St. Augustine**
>
> March 29-April 3, 2016   6-day, 100 miles (75 miles of walking and 25
>   miles of canoeing) to St. Augustine, FL, the oldest
>   continuously-settled city in the United States.   [Discover more about
>   this
>   pilgrimage>](http://sspx.org/en/news-events/calendar/pascua-florida-pilgrimage)
>
> **Cataldo Pilgrimage to Sacred Heart Mission**
>
> July 22-24, 2016   3-day, 50-mile to Sacred Heart Old Indian Mission
>   in Cataldo, ID, the oldest Catholic church in Northwest U.S., founded
>   by [Fr. Pierre-Jean De Smet](https://archive.org/details/lifeoffatherdesm00lave).   [Discover more about this
>   pilgrimage>](http://sspx.org/en/news-events/calendar/cataldo-pilgrimage)
>
> **Santa Fe Pilgrimage to Padilla Cross**
>
> July 22-23, 2016   33-miles overnight (men and boys only) to the
>   monument at Lyons, KS, erected to honor America's Protomartyr, Fr. Juan
>   de Padilla (+1542).   [Discover more about this
>   pilgrimage>](http://sspx.org/en/news-events/calendar/santa-fe-pilgrimage)

There's also a [Starkenburg Pilgrimage](http://sspx.org/en/media/video/starkenburg-pilgrimage-tradition-video-1847) and an [Auriesville, NY, pilgrimage](http://sspx.org/en/news-events/calendar/auriesville-pilgrimage-15208), which honors "a group of Jesuit priests and religious [who] were martyred by the Iroquois Indians" "over 400 years ago".

The American branch of [Tradition, Family, and Property (TFP)](http://www.tfp.org), a lay Catholic group, also does Marian pilgrimages.

Comment: It might be a bit of subterfuge to say that SSPX leads Catholic pilgrimages, but at least you're up front about it.   If a joe-schmo Catholic from a 'normal' parish were to attend one of those pilgrimages, would he be woo'ed away into the society?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the tradition is not yet established in the United States for the pilgrimages of the Roman Catholic Church. I vouch for keeping this list up to date. Do not hesitate to remount them.

[According to choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84216/are-there-any-formal-religious-pilgrimage-journeys-to-take-in-the-usa-or-canada/84346#84346) *there is probably nothing in North America directly comparable to the pilgrimage trails in the Old World; the continent was too recently settled and too lacking in sites associated with Jesus and the Apostles for such a culture to develop, and U.S. society was suspicious of, and sometimes outright violent against, Catholic and Orthodox worship until well into the 20th century.* And he gives most of the following list:

#### Yearly route

- The **[Camino del Norte a Chimayó](http://www.americanpilgrims.org/assets/documents/essays/carpenter_camino_norte_chimayo.pdf)**, which would follow a 115-mile (185 km) route over seven days from San Luis, Colorado to [El Santuario de Chimayo](http://www.elsantuariodechimayo.us/) in New Mexico, the most famous shrine in the Western U.S. [Since 2012](http://caminotochimayo.blogspot.com/), a group has made the journey once a year, but as elsewhere, there is no infrastructure to serve pilgrims. It is at best a route, not a trail, and very much in its infancy.

> [T]he Camino del Norte a Chimayó wanders along roadsides and forest trails through the sparsely-populated and desert-like sagebrush flats, rolling hills, and mountains of southern Colorado and northern New Mexico. One walks for as long as 20 miles (32 km) without a place to refill water bottles, purchase lunch or a snack, or even find a shady spot to rest for a few moments. Many of the villages and hamlets along the route have no commercial lodging or food markets, much less a café or restaurant. The only large town along the way is Taos, New
>   Mexico. Pilgrims along this route must therefore either camp out, carrying tents, food, and portable stoves, or if specifically planned in advance, stay overnight in church halls, sleeping on mats or air mattresses on hard floors.

- the **[Walking Pilgrimage to Doylestown](http://www.walkingpilgrimage.us/)** to visit the [National Shrine of Our Lady of Czestochowa](https://www.czestochowa.us/), sponsored by SS. Peter & Paul Church in Great Meadows, New Jersey annually since 1987. It is a selection of public trails going through public parkland. You are entirely on your own for camping, eating, and other arrangements.

#### Route

- The [**California Mission Trail**](http://www.californiamissionguide.com/california-mission-history/el-camino-real/el-camino-real-mission-walkers/) along El Camino Real from the southernmost mission in San Diego to the northermost in Sonoma. No year-round route. [Thanks to Paula](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/92477/75631)

#### Single-day walking events.

- In Washington, D.C., for example, the Archdiocese has organized a Lenten 7-Church Walk annually since 2003, in loose imitation of the traditional walks to the seven Pilgrim Churches of Rome. But the itinerary changes year to year, and again, there is no dedicated path, just public sidewalks and streets.